# Database is not updating after running stored procedure in asp app

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an asp app that should be able to let a user update an entry in a sql server database. When I run my stored procedure though in my method, nothing happens to the database.

```
public void updateFeature(Feature updatedFeature)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(updatedFeature.Environment)))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "usp_UpdateFeature";
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeatureName", updatedFeature.FeatureName);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeatureID", updatedFeature.FeatureID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeatureDescription", updatedFeature.Description);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldName", updatedFeature.FieldName);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnOffSwitch", updatedFeature.IsOn);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChannelID", updatedFeature.ChannelID);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", updatedFeature.ProductID);                

        sqlConnection.Open();
        int numberOfRowsChanged =  sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

and my stored procedure looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateFeature]  
(  
 @FeatureID int,  
 @FeatureName varchar(30),  
 @FeatureDescription varchar(200) = null,  
 @FieldName varchar(40),  
 @OnOffSwitch bit,
 @ChannelID varchar(3),
 @ProductID varchar(2)
)  
AS  

SET NOCOUNT ON  

UPDATE FM_Feature   
SET FeatureName = @FeatureName,   
 FeatureDescription = @FeatureDescription,   
 FieldName = @FieldName,   
 OnOffSwitch = @OnOffSwitch, 
 ProductID = @ProductID,
 ChannelID = @ChannelID 
WHERE FeatureID = @FeatureID
```

The numberOfRowsChanged parameter returns -1 but I do not get any exceptions or errors. Is there something that I am missing or not understanding?

Comment: with `set nocount on;` you are telling the server not to count ("nocount") the number of rows affected, so it returns -1. does the data get updated?

Comment: Did you verify in the db if the data is actually updated ?

Comment: What did you see in Sql Profiler while you ran your code (and stored proc)?

Comment: I verified the data s not updated

Comment: @TZHX thanks for that tip, I removed that line and I get the number of rows changed as being 1 (what I would expect) but the data did not get updated in the database.

Comment: Then you have another problem. Run the stored procedure manually.

Comment: If you are updating 1 row and the data doesn't change than your Feature parameter still holds the old values. Or the FeatureID was wrong. Really only 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to open your connection before you create your command, i hope that will be helpful for you .

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(updatedFeature.Environment))

sqlConnection.Open();

using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.CommandText = "usp_UpdateFeature";
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeatureName", updatedFeature.FeatureName);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeatureID", updatedFeature.FeatureID);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FeatureDescription", updatedFeature.Description);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldName", updatedFeature.FieldName);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnOffSwitch", updatedFeature.IsOn);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChannelID", updatedFeature.ChannelID);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", updatedFeature.ProductID);                

    int numberOfRowsChanged =  sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

enjoy it .